# Deleting Entire Rows from Source After Pasting Into New Sheet

Tags: excel, loops, row

Everything in this code works well until the piece where I need to delete the rows in column "I" of the source tab ("Status Report").  I have to run this macro several times to clear out all of the rows I want to delete because it appears to only delete one row at a time.

How can I get this macro to delete all of the rows I want and only run this code once?

```
Sub CopyYes()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("I1:I1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
    If c = 1 Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
       Source.Rows(c.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next c
```

End Sub

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is better to start Last Row up for delete to work correctly

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip yass!  How would I write that into the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is this? It, as suggested by @yass, starts at the last row and works backwards.

```
Sub CopyYes()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Dim lastRow As Long

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

blankRow = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet

lastRow = 1000
' lastRow = Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row ' Uncomment this line if you want to do ALL rows in column I

With Source
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 9).Value = 1 Then
            If blankRow = 1 Then
                .Rows(i).Copy Target.Rows(blankRow)
            Else
                .Rows(i).Copy Target.Rows(blankRow + 1)
            End If
            blankRow = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
           .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Note: The main difference is the `For` loop. AFAIK you can't do a `For each x in Range` loop backwards.

Comment: Huge thanks for your help BruceWayne : )  I added "End If" right before "Next i" and it worked like a charm!

Comment: @Wendy - Ah, d'oh! I forgot to do that, but edited it in. Glad it worked!

Comment: One more question if that's ok.  How can I change "j" so that data starts copying after the last row of data?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Wendy what do you mean? You want to change j to ...? Do you want the copied range (on the Target) sheet to be in the same order as Source?

Comment: I want the data being copied into the target sheet to begin pasting entire rows in the first blank row (I would use the 1st column in the destination sheet to determine where to paste).  Does that make better sense?

Comment: @Wendy - Ah, yeah. See the edit. Is that what you meant?